# How to set a daemon for one specific user to start when he logs in and stop when he logs out?

Tags: ubuntu

I work for a company that made us to install a software that checks our activity. For this purpose, I created a new user for this purpose only called 'work'. The software is called 'wtcd' and it is a daemon service when I install that and run it manually with `systemctl start wtcd` when I login to `work` user and stop it when I log out of this user. And when my working hours end, I log out of this user, stop this service again and login to my personal user.

I gave administrative permissions to `work` user and is included in `sudoer` file.

I want to know whether it's possible to do this: When `work` user only logs in, the command `sudo systemctl start wtcd` run in background, and when this user logs out, it runs `sudo systemctl stop wtcd`.

How can I do this? I did only find a way to start it on startup, but nothing to do in the end when logging out.

Comment: Saeed, you might explain what you did to make it start up too to show some effort you already put into it. Looks like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh might be helpful to you ask well